# No desktop appears on HP 1240US

Tags: drivers

I have an HP PAVILLION 1240US.

I downloaded Ubuntu for the first time to try Linux. Everything worked perfectly for two weeks, then it gave me a message saying there was an update. Now there is no desktop at all. I have even tried to reload the OS for scratch and it still won't come back.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try an other driver (experimential maby)

do ctrl + alt + t and type this command:

```
gnome-control-center
```

This will bring up the settings panel.

Do software sources and than additional drivers.

And select an other driver.

If there are no drivers founded. I suggest to read this.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

If this not work take a good look at your grub menu normaly there will be an option "Boot with older version of linux". And select the oldest image.

Comment: his desktop isn't even showing... [Ctrl][Alt][F1] and doing cli might be more helpful!  ;-)

Comment: Yeah, on older ubuntu version the terminal still showed up if unity crashed (or not loaded). Now thats indeed the only solution. If I clean install, I always install a minimalistic desktop (like fluxbox) for cases like this.